# Is there a Java-applet implementation of HTML5 WebSockets?

Tags: java, sockets, applet, html

Is there a Java-applet implementation of HTML5 WebSockets?

I'd like to use WebSockets for a new project, and provide a backward compatible implementation of WebSockets (for all current non-dev browsers) using Java (or maybe Flash).

I only want to write and maintain WebSockets on the server-side.  I only want to have to deal with the WebSockets API on the client side (though this API will be 'faked' by a Java-applet, if real WebSockets aren't available).

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation (uses Flash as a fallback):

http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

No guarantees (I'm away from my development environment right now), but it looks like it'll do what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks useful - I will test.  

I'm concerned about the proxy CONNECT issue, but this may not be an issue.  

So long as the websocket server runs on a different port number and the user's firewall allows outgoing connections to that port, this may be a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is one, please have look at http://www.jwebsocket.org.
Your jWebSocket Team.

Comment: Thanks, that look like just what I need.  Deploying a web app using jwebsocket and web-socket-js should cover 95%+ of non-chrome browsers.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Java-applet implementation of WebSockets.
At least from your description, and your demo, which rejects Firefox 3.6 as non compatible: so I suppose client side is currently only in JS on compatible browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking as a representative of [Kaazing](http://www.kaazing.com):

We have [another solution](https://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/) that provides support for Java, Flash, Silverlight, and JS, and backward compatibility with all pre-Websocket browsers. [Documentation is located here](https://kaazing.com/documentation/).

Comment: Thanks for this info, but I'd already disregarded it due to their licence: http://www.kaazing.com/license

Comment: 5. PROHIBITED USES. Developer may not: (a) remove or modify any software markings or any notice of Kaazing's proprietary rights; (b) **redistribute** or make the programs available in any manner to any third party;

Emphasis is mine.

Comment: The Kaazing WebSocket Gateway has been [available as an open source project under the Apache 2.0 license](https://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/) since 2014.